# How to load sibling module file in Rust?

Tags: rust, module

everyone, here is my "models" module:

[image]

in mod.rs I do re-export:

```
mod distribution;
mod item;
mod project;
mod relation;

pub use distribution::Distribution;
pub use item::Item;
pub use project::Project;
pub use relation::Relation;
```

In main.rs Seem to work fine:

```
mod models;
use models::Item;
use models::Project;
use models::Relation;
use models::Distribution;
```

But how can I use Distribution inside Item (models/item.rs)?

I tried:

```
mod models;
use models::Distribution;
```

or

```
mod distribution;
use distribution::Distribution;
```

But compiler can't find relevant file.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I found the answer, so let it be here:

```
// models/item.rs
use crate::models::Distribution;
```

Comment: `use super::Distribution` should work too.

Comment: Thank you, that's even better!