# Importing a sibling module in a submodule does not resolve

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand how to split code into multiple files in Rust.

When executing `cargo run` I get this:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::path`
 --> util/message.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use super::path;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `path` in `util`
```

The file layout and contents are thus:

./util/path.rs

```
pub const PATHFILE_PATH:&str = "~/.PATH";
```

./util/message.rs

```
use super::path;

pub fn display_message() {
    println!("{}", path.PATHFILE_PATH);
}
```

./main.rs

```
mod util;

fn main() {
    util::message::display_message();
}
```

./util.rs

```
pub mod message;
```

As far as I can tell, I am doing what is expected. [Previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74338273/how-to-load-sibling-module-file-in-rust) as well as [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html) seem to confirm I am doing the right thing, and yet, I fail.

Can anyone help me identify what I've done wrong please?

[The full layout is also on github](https://github.com/taikedz/pathctl/tree/WIP-isolate-path/src)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `src/utils.rs` file should contain

```rust
pub mod path;
```

You could also move `src/util.rs` to `src/util/mod.rs` (not required anymore since edition 2018).

```
src/
├── pathctl.rs
└── util
    ├── display.rs
    ├── mod.rs
    └── path.rs
```

By the way, `PATHFILE_PATH` should be qualified as `pub` in `path.rs`.

Comment: Interesting. The missing part of my understanding is that the module _file_ must declare the submodule parts, even for the submodules themselves to recognise eachother... I hadn't realised that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the code in the linked repository, your `util` module definition in `util.rs` does not contain a `mod path` statement to load the `path` submodule. Unlike say Python packages, the Rust compiler does not automatically create a module for every file in the module subdirectory - you have to explicitly tell the compiler to load modules from a file.